# cp all files in the same directory, but exclude subdirectories/files

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, cp

I'm looking for a way to do something like this:

```
cp -R jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified ui
```

..but to let it match all files in the `minified` folder (and only it's root) and except all subdirectories/files.

The folder has 1 subfolder called `images`, but want to exclude cases in the future when it might have more directories.

I could just remove the `images` directory afterwards, but it might give problems if more subfolders arise in future releases of `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is not to pass the `-R` flag:

```
cp jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/* ui
```

From `man cp`:

```
   -R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

By default, `cp` does not recurse into sub directories and only copies files.

---

If for whatever weird reason the default behavior of `cp` fails, you can always use find:

```
find -type f jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/* -exec cp "{}" ui \;
```

Comment: Sorry; I forgot to note I'm using OSX. I get an error while using `cp -R jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/* ui` gives `usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvX] source_file ... target_directory`.

Comment: @Allendar Ummm... why are you giving the `-R` flag? The whole point was to _not_ pass the `-R` flag. This operation does not require the `-R` flag, it is an `-R` flag-less situation. (sorry re-watched the parrot sketch recently).

Comment: Correction; `cp jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/minified/* ui` gives that usage-message.

Comment: Does `ui` exist and is it a directory? Do you have your paths correctly? Do both source and target directories exist? Are you copy/pasting the _exact_ command you ran or could there be a syntax error I don't see? What I am suggesting here is very basic `cp` usage. Don't have access to a mac at the moment but the OSX [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html) agrees with me.

Comment: I just tested it (on OS X) and confirmed it working. No idea why you'd get a usage message unless `ui` wasn't a directory (or not existing at all). In that case you *do* get the OP's error.